# Double negative in SQL - meaning of NOT (Food != "Apple")

Tags: sql, logic, conceptual, logic-programming

Having trouble with double negative meaning.

Are these statements equivalent?

1. NOT (Food <> "Apple" AND NOT (Food = "Banana"))

===

2. (Food = "Apple" AND Food = "Banana")

Comment: it should be `Food = "Apple" OR Food = "Banana"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

```
NOT( A OR B )  = NOT A AND NOT B
NOT( A AND B ) = NOT A OR  NOT B
```

So first sentence should be:

```
NOT (Food <> "Apple" AND NOT (Food = "Banana"))
==> NOT (Food <> "Apple" AND Food <> "Banana")       -- SOLVE inner NOT
==> NOT (Food <> "Apple") OR NOT (Food <> "Banana")  -- MORGAN LAW
==> Food = "Apple" OR Food = "Banana"                -- APPLY NOT
```